# Packages related to Video will not upgrade

Tags: package-management, upgrade

I am running Ubuntu 18.04 on a desktop I use for video production and my media center. The Kdenlive and Audacity programs are working well, as does Kodi. I have no issues watching videos from any web browser.

I wanted to install Handbreak to convert some video files into a different format. I was unable to do so because I had broken packages like libavcode58. After several hours of looking for, and trying different solutions, I was doing more harm than good to my computer.

So I used the Timeshift program to go back to the state I was in prior to all the trial and error, and I installed Handbreak on my backup rig. Problem solved. And I am fine with "if it ain't broke don't fix it". All that being said:

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  ffmpeg kodi kodi-inputstream-rtmp kodi-peripheral-joystick kodi-pvr-hts
  libavcodec-dev libavutil-dev libchromaprint1 libgstreamer-plugins- 
  good1.0-0 libmlt++3 libswresample-dev libvlc-bin libvlc5 vlc-bin vlc- 
  data vlc-l10n vlc-plugin-notify vlc-plugin-samba vlc-plugin- 
  visualization
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 19 not upgraded.
```

I have several packages being held back from upgrade. It bugs me to just leave them there in that state. What should I do?

```
sudo apt upgrade ffmpeg
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
    The following information may help to resolve the situation:

    The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ffmpeg : Depends: libavcodec58 (>= 10:4.1.4) but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: libavdevice58 (>= 10:4.1.4) but it is not going to 
be installed
          Depends: libavfilter7 (>= 10:4.1.4) but it is not going to 
be installed
          Depends: libavformat58 (>= 10:4.1.4) but it is not going to 
be installed
          Depends: libavresample4 (>= 10:4.1.4) but it is not going to 
be installed
          Depends: libavutil56 (>= 10:4.1.4) but it is not going to be 
installed
          Depends: libpostproc55 (>= 10:4.1.4) but it is not going to 
be installed
          Depends: libswresample3 (>= 10:4.1.4) but it is not going to 
be installed
          Depends: libswscale5 (>= 10:4.1.4) but it is not going to be 
installed
        E: Broken packages


 sudo apt-cache policy
        [sudo] password for oneputtmike: 
        Package files:
         100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
             release a=now
         500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/teejee2008/ppa/ubuntu 
bionic/main 
    i386 
        Packages
         release v=18.04,o=LP-PPA- 
   teejee2008,a=bionic,n=bionic,l=Development,c=main,b=i386
         origin ppa.launchpad.net
     500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/teejee2008/ppa/ubuntu bionic/main 
amd64 
    Packages
         release v=18.04,o=LP-PPA- 
   teejee2008,a=bionic,n=bionic,l=Development,c=main,b=amd64
         origin ppa.launchpad.net
     500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/team-xbmc/ppa/ubuntu bionic/main 
i386 
    Packages
         release v=18.04,o=LP-PPA-team-xbmc,a=bionic,n=bionic,l=Kodi 
    stable,c=main,b=i386
         origin ppa.launchpad.net
     500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/team-xbmc/ppa/ubuntu bionic/main 
amd64 
    Packages
         release v=18.04,o=LP-PPA-team-xbmc,a=bionic,n=bionic,l=Kodi 
    stable,c=main,b=amd64
         origin ppa.launchpad.net
     500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/stebbins/handbrake-releases/ubuntu 
    bionic/main amd64 Packages
         release v=18.04,o=LP-PPA-stebbins-handbrake- 
   releases,a=bionic,n=bionic,l=HandBrake Releases,c=main,b=amd64
         origin ppa.launchpad.net
     500 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_10.x bionic/main amd64 
 Packages
         release o=Node Source,n=bionic,l=Node Source,c=main,b=amd64
         origin deb.nodesource.com
     500 http://apt.keepsolid.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
         release o=apt.keepsolid.com,n=bionic,l=KeepSolid apt 
    repository,c=main,b=amd64
         origin apt.keepsolid.com
     500 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable/main amd64 
Packages
         release v=1.0,o=Google 
    LLC,a=stable,n=stable,l=Google,c=main,b=amd64
         origin dl.google.com
     500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gezakovacs/ppa/ubuntu bionic/main 
i386 
    Packages
         release v=18.04,o=LP-PPA- 
   gezakovacs,a=bionic,n=bionic,l=UNetbootin PPA,c=main,b=i386
         origin ppa.launchpad.net
     500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gezakovacs/ppa/ubuntu bionic/main 
amd64 
    Packages
         release v=18.04,o=LP-PPA- 
   gezakovacs,a=bionic,n=bionic,l=UNetbootin PPA,c=main,b=amd64
         origin ppa.launchpad.net
     500 https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com bionic/main 
amd64 
    Packages
         release o=. bionic,a=bionic,n=bionic,l=. 
bionic,c=main,b=amd64
         origin brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com
     500 http://www.deb-multimedia.org sid/main i386 Packages
         release o=Unofficial Multimedia 
    Packages,a=unstable,n=sid,l=Unofficial Multimedia 
    Packages,c=main,b=i386
         origin www.deb-multimedia.org
     500 http://www.deb-multimedia.org sid/main amd64 Packages
        release o=Unofficial Multimedia 
    Packages,a=unstable,n=sid,l=Unofficial Multimedia 
    Packages,c=main,b=amd64
         origin www.deb-multimedia.org
     500 http://la-mirrors.evowise.com/ubuntu bionic- 
   security/multiverse 
    i386 Packages
         release v=18.04,o=Ubuntu,a=bionic- 
   security,n=bionic,l=Ubuntu,c=multiverse,b=i386
         origin la-mirrors.evowise.com
     500 http://la-mirrors.evowise.com/ubuntu bionic- 
   security/multiverse 
    amd64 Packages
         release v=18.04,o=Ubuntu,a=bionic- 
   security,n=bionic,l=Ubuntu,c=multiverse,b=amd64
         origin la-mirrors.evowise.com
     500 http://la-mirrors.evowise.com/ubuntu bionic-security/universe 
    i386 Packages
         release v=18.04,o=Ubuntu,a=bionic- 
   security,n=bionic,l=Ubuntu,c=universe,b=i386
     origin la-mirrors.evowise.com
    500 http://la-mirrors.evowise.com/ubuntu bionic-security/universe 
    amd64 Packages
     release v=18.04,o=Ubuntu,a=bionic- 
   security,n=bionic,l=Ubuntu,c=universe,b=amd64
     origin la-mirrors.evowise.com
    500 http://la-mirrors.evowise.com/ubuntu bionic- 
   security/restricted 
    i386 Packages
        release v=18.04,o=Ubuntu,a=bionic- 
   security,n=bionic,l=Ubuntu,c=restricted,b=i386
     origin la-mirrors.evowise.com
    500 http://la-mirrors.evowise.com/ubuntu bionic- 
     security/restricted 
    amd64 Packages
         release v=18.04,o=Ubuntu,a=bionic- 
   security,n=bionic,l=Ubuntu,c=restricted,b=amd64
         origin la-mirrors.evowise.com
     500 http://la-mirrors.evowise.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main 
i386 
    Packages
         release v=18.04,o=Ubuntu,a=bionic- 
   security,n=bionic,l=Ubuntu,c=main,b=i386
         origin la-mirrors.evowise.com
     500 http://la-mirrors.evowise.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main 
amd64 
    Packages
         release v=18.04,o=Ubuntu,a=bionic- 
   security,n=bionic,l=Ubuntu,c=main,b=amd64
         origin la-mirrors.evowise.com
     500 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic/partner i386 
Packages
         release v=18.04,o=Canonical,a=bionic,n=bionic,l=Partner 
    archive,c=partner,b=i386
         origin archive.canonical.com
     500 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic/partner amd64 
Packages
         release v=18.04,o=Canonical,a=bionic,n=bionic,l=Partner 
    archive,c=partner,b=amd64
         origin archive.canonical.com
     100 http://la-mirrors.evowise.com/ubuntu bionic- 
backports/universe 
    i386 Packages
         release v=18.04,o=Ubuntu,a=bionic- 
   backports,n=bionic,l=Ubuntu,c=universe,b=i386
         origin la-mirrors.evowise.com
     100 http://la-mirrors.evowise.com/ubuntu bionic- 
   backports/universe 
    amd64 Packages
         release v=18.04,o=Ubuntu,a=bionic- 
   backports,n=bionic,l=Ubuntu,c=universe,b=amd64
        origin la-mirrors.evowise.com
     100 http://la-mirrors.evowise.com/ubuntu bionic-backports/main 
    i386 
    Packages
         release v=18.04,o=Ubuntu,a=bionic- 
   backports,n=bionic,l=Ubuntu,c=main,b=i386
     origin la-mirrors.evowise.com
     100 http://la-mirrors.evowise.com/ubuntu bionic-backports/main 
amd64 
    Packages
         release v=18.04,o=Ubuntu,a=bionic- 
   backports,n=bionic,l=Ubuntu,c=main,b=amd64
     origin la-mirrors.evowise.com
     500 http://la-mirrors.evowise.com/ubuntu bionic- 
    updates/multiverse 
    i386 Packages
     release v=18.04,o=Ubuntu,a=bionic- 
    updates,n=bionic,l=Ubuntu,c=multiverse,b=i386
     origin la-mirrors.evowise.com
     500 http://la-mirrors.evowise.com/ubuntu bionic- 
   updates/multiverse 
    amd64 Packages
     release v=18.04,o=Ubuntu,a=bionic- 
    updates,n=bionic,l=Ubuntu,c=multiverse,b=amd64
     origin la-mirrors.evowise.com
     500 http://la-mirrors.evowise.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe 
i386 
    Packages
     release v=18.04,o=Ubuntu,a=bionic- 
   updates,n=bionic,l=Ubuntu,c=universe,b=i386
     origin la-mirrors.evowise.com
     500 http://la-mirrors.evowise.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe 
    amd64 Packages
    release v=18.04,o=Ubuntu,a=bionic- 
   updates,n=bionic,l=Ubuntu,c=universe,b=amd64
     origin la-mirrors.evowise.com
     500 http://la-mirrors.evowise.com/ubuntu bionic- 
   updates/restricted 
    i386 Packages
     release v=18.04,o=Ubuntu,a=bionic- 
    updates,n=bionic,l=Ubuntu,c=restricted,b=i386
     origin la-mirrors.evowise.com
     500 http://la-mirrors.evowise.com/ubuntu bionic- 
    updates/restricted 
    amd64 Packages
     release v=18.04,o=Ubuntu,a=bionic- 
    updates,n=bionic,l=Ubuntu,c=restricted,b=amd64
     origin la-mirrors.evowise.com
     500 http://la-mirrors.evowise.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main i386 
    Packages
    release v=18.04,o=Ubuntu,a=bionic- 
    updates,n=bionic,l=Ubuntu,c=main,b=i386
     origin la-mirrors.evowise.com
     500 http://la-mirrors.evowise.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main 
    amd64 
    Packages
     release v=18.04,o=Ubuntu,a=bionic- 
    updates,n=bionic,l=Ubuntu,c=main,b=amd64
     origin la-mirrors.evowise.com
     500 http://la-mirrors.evowise.com/ubuntu bionic/multiverse i386 
    Packages
     release 
    v=18.04,o=Ubuntu,a=bionic,n=bionic,l=Ubuntu,c=multiverse,b=i386
     origin la-mirrors.evowise.com
     500 http://la-mirrors.evowise.com/ubuntu bionic/multiverse amd64 
    Packages
     release 
    v=18.04,o=Ubuntu,a=bionic,n=bionic,l=Ubuntu,c=multiverse,b=amd64
     origin la-mirrors.evowise.com
     500 http://la-mirrors.evowise.com/ubuntu bionic/universe i386 
    Packages
     release 
    v=18.04,o=Ubuntu,a=bionic,n=bionic,l=Ubuntu,c=universe,b=i386
     origin la-mirrors.evowise.com
     500 http://la-mirrors.evowise.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 
    Packages
     release 
    v=18.04,o=Ubuntu,a=bionic,n=bionic,l=Ubuntu,c=universe,b=amd64
     origin la-mirrors.evowise.com
     500 http://la-mirrors.evowise.com/ubuntu bionic/restricted i386 
    Packages
     release 
    v=18.04,o=Ubuntu,a=bionic,n=bionic,l=Ubuntu,c=restricted,b=i386
     origin la-mirrors.evowise.com
     500 http://la-mirrors.evowise.com/ubuntu bionic/restricted amd64 
    Packages
     release 
    v=18.04,o=Ubuntu,a=bionic,n=bionic,l=Ubuntu,c=restricted,b=amd64
     origin la-mirrors.evowise.com
     500 http://la-mirrors.evowise.com/ubuntu bionic/main i386 
     Packages
     release v=18.04,o=Ubuntu,a=bionic,n=bionic,l=Ubuntu,c=main,b=i386
     origin la-mirrors.evowise.com
     500 http://la-mirrors.evowise.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 
     Packages
     release 
    v=18.04,o=Ubuntu,a=bionic,n=bionic,l=Ubuntu,c=main,b=amd64
     origin la-mirrors.evowise.com
        Pinned packages:
```

Comment: `apt-cache policy` and please show also `apt upgrade ffmpeg`

Comment: Basically, when you add a third-party repository and install packages from it, don't remove the repository afterwards while leaving the packages installed. If you want to remove the repository, revert the packages back to the official ones.

Comment: I don't know how to revert the packages back to the official ones. I don't remember what repositories I have or may have removed.

Comment: @nobody
I have added the requested info to the post.

Comment: @fkraiem "add athird-party repository and install packages from it, don't remove the repository afterwards while leaving the packages installed." While that is good advice I will follow in the future, I still don't know how to solve my problem. Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

Wow, worster than I thought. In my opinion save your data's and install new.
Never use Debian package source in ubuntu.

If you want uptodate packages use a rolling release Distro like Arch.

Comment: Another lesson learned. Don't remove the repository and never use Debian package source in Ubuntu. Got it. Thank you for that honest assessment. Now I have a project for the weekend, hooray!

Comment: While I wouldn't mark this tread as solved, I no longer have the problem. I followed the advice from @nobody. I saved my data and installed a new Ubuntu OS. Fortunately I had my OS on a small SSD and my home directory on a separate drive. 

Thanks for the help, and best wishes everyone.